# Trying to Create an Array of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a school project that requires me to sort 50 sets of integers of n size for 10 values of n.  I have the sorting methods all worked out but what I can't figure out is how to package these monster arrays in order to loop them through the sorts.

My original thought was an array of two-dimensional arrays.  I'm trying to stay away from ArrayList because I don't want to deal with the headache of downcasting integers.  So my question is, is there a way to do something like:

```
private array[] fullList; //this is where I would store my 2-dimensional arrays
private int[n][50] sets; //this is where I would have my 50 sets of n length
```

Thoughts?

Okay, since I can't figure out to put it in the comments, this is what I came up with:

```
 public BenchmarkSorts(int[] sizes) {
        for (int i=0; i < sizes.length; i++){
           set = int[(sizes[i])][50]
              for (int row=0; row < sizes[i]; j++)
                 for (int column=0; column < 50; column++)
                    set[row][column] = rdm.nextInt();    
        fullList.add(i, set);
        }
```

I wish I could use the ArrayList sort but it is an Algorithm Design Class and I have to do it the hard way.

But, now it won't let me use `sizes[i]` in the second line to initate the value of the array `set`... any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to "deal with the headache of downcasting integers" with Java 1.5+ (which is very old at this point), which provides [auto(un)boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: very true @MattBall. If we work with list or set family things will become easy.

Comment: ArrayLists are dynamic and pretty well optimized inside Java. So just stick to them when you need any kind of array functionality. They work well in most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList would be much better choice. You can create generic arraylist of inetegers and that should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

you can sort int arrays using `Arrays.sort(`)
`ArrayList` is more handy. But it needs at least 4 times the memory, but that is only important if your arrays are huge.